# Which RAID configuration should I go with for fault-tolerance?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, comparison

On my work PC, I'm running a RAID 1 currently.

I have an opportunity to upgrade my system and I'm wondering what is the best setup I can use.

I have 4 available hard drives and I definitely need fault-tolerance. I heard that RAID 10 is better than RAID 5.

Which configuration should I go with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raid 10 is better than raid5

- Raid 5 you can lose at most one disk
- Raid 10 you can lose two disks as long as they're not from the same pair
- Raid 10 is faster

Personally, I feel raid5 is a bit of a waste on 4 disks - it leaves you with the capacity of n-1 disks whereas raid10 gives you a capacity of n/2 disks. If you have 10 disks then there's a sigificant amount of space lost by choosing raid10, but with 4 disks it's not nearly as significant.

If you can afford to give up the extra space then go with raid 10.

Comment: Well, RAID 10 is certainly the "Rolls-Royce" of RAID configruations. Guess it really boils down to a) do I really feel I need it, and b) can I afford to buy that many disks...

Comment: c) Does my RAID adapter support RAID10?

Comment: "raid5 is a bit of a waste on 4 disks" - more than that: on an array this small, it's outright dangerous ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_5_write_hole et al) when compared to RAID 10.

Answer (score 1):

Raid 10 is a massive waste of space, and the benefits you might get in redundancy can be just as easily achieved with sort sort of offsite or cloud backup. Raid 5 is usually good enough since it's only really broken if two drives fail, which is extremely rare.

Comment: If you had 4 500gb disks, then you're looking at a total usable space of 1.5gb vs 1gb (for raid5 vs. raid10). That isn't really a massive waste of space for something that will be faster.

Comment: I guess that depends how big your work's hardware budget is...

Comment: "if two drives fail, which is extremely rare" - this is only rare if your disks are uncorrelated. Example: we bought a server with 4 disks, all were from the same batch, one failed after ~1000 hours, another a few hundred hours later. A bad batch, probably (manufacturer replaced them without any opposition at all, I suspect we weren't the only ones affected; the other two are still in service AFAIK).